# Clojure jdbc weird response for sum

Tags: jdbc, clojure

Im'm trying to execute a simple sum aggregation of two count queries:

```
(jdbc/query (db-connection)
        "SELECT sum(t.count) AS count FROM (select 1 AS count union select 2 AS count) t")
=> ({:count 3})

(jdbc/query (db-connection)
        "select count(1) from table_a")
=> ({:count 0})

(jdbc/query (db-connection)
        "select count(1) from table_b")
=> ({:count 0})

(jdbc/query (db-connection)
        "SELECT sum(t.count) AS count FROM (select count(1) from table_a union select count(1) from table_b) t")
=> ({:count 0M})
```

0M

Why 0M? Why M? What is going on?

EDIT2: This is the BigDecimal notation. I would still like to know why it is suddenly using BigDecimal. Is `sum` treated differently in JDBC? Is the db (postgres) returning a different data type for `sum`?

EDIT 3: Postgres returns the generic `numeric` type for the sum aggregation. This is converted to a BigDecimal in JDBC.

So another way to consistently get the same type of return value would be to make the cast in the query:

```
(jdbc/query (db-connection)
    "SELECT sum(t.count)::bigint AS count FROM (select count(1) from table_a union select count(1) from table_b) t")
=> ({:count 423602})
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a duplicate, but it might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814317/why-does-m-appear-in-clojure-mysql-query-results

Answer (score 1):

As jas brought up, this is the BigDecimal notation. You can convert a BigDecimal to a double simply with `(double value)` - even to just long if you are sure you don't need fractions.

EDIT: the actual solution:

```
(extend-protocol jdbc/ISQLValue

BigDecimal
(sql-value [value] (long value)))
```

Comment: keep in mind that this may throw an exception if the value really doesn't fit in a long

Comment: Good point. In my case the sum is always in tens of thousands and the data size grows very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of the result in the database. For PostgreSQL try this:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(SUM(count)) FROM table_a;
```

You can explicitly cast to the desired type:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(SUM(count)::bigint) FROM table_a;
```

which should fix it. (Don't forget to remove the `pg_typeof()` function call.) [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-aggregate.html) is more information about the SUM function.